# Xtext - Custom made terminal string without quotes

Tags: eclipse, xtext

I´m new to Xtext and have a problem.

When I try to create a terminal String without quotes I always get EOF errors.

If I comment out the code for the String without quotes I´dont get an error and everything works fine.

Can someone explain me this?
Or give me some hint how I could better solve this?

Thank you very much

```
    // String without quotes
terminal STRINGWQ: ( ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z')('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_'| '-' | '§' | '?' | '!'| '@'
                                        | '\n' | ':' |'%' | '.' | '*' | '^' | ',' | '&' | '('|')'| '0'..'9'|' ')*);
```

Rest of Code

```
grammar org.xtext.example.mydsl.MyDsl with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals

generate myDsl "http://www.xtext.org/example/mydsl/MyDsl"


Model:
    (elements += GITest)* 
;


GITest:
    KWHeader | KWTestCase
;

// KeyWords Header
KWHeader:
    'Test' '!''?'
    ;

KWTestCase:
    'testcase' int=INT ':' title = ID |
    'Hello' names=ID '!'
;
```

UPDATE:
Data Type Rule

```
 QSTRING returns ecore::EString: //custom terminal SurveyString
        (('a'|'b'|'c'|'d'|'e'|'f'|'g'|'h'|'i'|'j'|'k'|'l'|'m'|'n'|'o'|'p'|'q'|'r'|'s'|'t'|'u'|'v'|'w'|'x'|'y'|'z'|
           'A'|'B'|'C'|'D'|'E'|'F'|'G'|'H'|'I'|'J'|'K'|'L'|'M'|'N'|'O'|'P'|'Q'|'R'|'S'|'T'|'U'|'V'|'W'|'X'|'Y'|'Z'|' ')
          ('a'|'b'|'c'|'d'|'e'|'f'|'g'|'h'|'i'|'j'|'k'|'l'|'m'|'n'|'o'|'p'|'q'|'r'|'s'|'t'|'u'|'v'|'w'|'x'|'y'|'z'|
           'A'|'B'|'C'|'D'|'E'|'F'|'G'|'H'|'I'|'J'|'K'|'L'|'M'|'N'|'O'|'P'|'Q'|'R'|'S'|'T'|'U'|'V'|'W'|'X'|'Y'|'Z'|
           ' '|'_'|'-'|'§'|'?'|'!'|'@'|'%'|'.'|'*'|'^'|','|'&'|'('|')'|'0'|'1'|'2'|'3'|'4'|'5'|'6'|'7'|'8'|'9')*);
```

UPDATE 2:

Got it working with Data Type Rule und manipulating ID

Code:

```
STRINGWQ: ((' ')?ID)((ID)?(INT)? ' ' (ID)?);
terminal ID: '^'?('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_'|'0'..'9'|'/'|';'|','|'#'|'!'|'§'|'$'|'%'|'&'|
              '('|')'|'='|'?'|'\\'|'*'|'+'|'.'|'-'|'>'|'<'|'|'|'['|']'|'{'|'}')*;
```

But now I have the problem that xtext not recognizes when STRINGWQ ends.
So I dont get keyword suggestions in the next line.
For example if i dont use STRINGWQ but INT I get suggestions in the next line.
But with STRINGWQ I dont.
How can I define an end of Data Type Rules? 
Thank you

Comment: Do you get the EOF-error before writing anything or after having started typing something?

Comment: I started typing something and then eclipse shows up an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
Property:
    id=ID | int=INT | prop=PROPERTY_VALUE | spec=SPECIAL;

PROPERTY_VALUE:
    (':');

SPECIAL:
    (' ' | '/' | ';' | ',' | '!' | '§' | '%' | '&' | '(' | ')' | '?' | '*' | '+' | '.' | '-' | '|' | '[' | ']')
```

I separated the colon as I need to use PROPERTY_VALUE in another way.
But you also could add it to special.

Answer (score 3):

Your STRINGWQ shadows the terminal rule ID and basically all other rules including the keywords. Chances are good that the entire document will by consumed as a single terminal token of type STRINGWQ. You should try to model your string as a datatype rule.

Comment: I tried it but its not working. I added the Data Type Rule above. With this rule I get on every INT this error " mismatched input ' ' expecting RULE_INT" and on a String "extraneous input 'Text' expecting EOF" Thank you